# How to set the null value when an MismatchedInputException?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I Have a class like this ;

```java
public class User  {
  public String username;
  public String password;
}
```

json

```
{"username": "test","password": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9]}
```

When I run this code ;

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
User user = objectMapper.readValue(json, User.class);
```

It throw an exception;

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
```

But I just want get a user like this;

```
  username=test;
  password=null;
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you _want_ to do this, when the input clearly doesn't match? This indicates that there is some kind of error, and it's best to [fail noisily and as soon as possible](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s06.html) rather than silently continue.

Comment: instead of using `password=null;` try to use `password="";`.

Comment: The explanation is very complicated, but mainly because of the historical problems left behind;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to register custom `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler`. In case you want to read a `String` but you have an array you can return `null`. Simple implementation:

```
objectMapper.addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
    @Override
    public Object handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext ctxt, JavaType targetType, JsonToken t, JsonParser p, String failureMsg) throws IOException {
        if (targetType.getRawClass() == String.class && t == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
            return null;
        }
        return super.handleUnexpectedToken(ctxt, targetType, t, p, failureMsg);
    }
});
```